# Any possible to make xref--marker-ring 'project-local'?

Tags: emacs, navigation, project

I use eglot in my daily workflow, but find one annoying issue when working on multiple project concurrently. Steps below explain my issue:

1. Use xref-find-definitions in project A.
2. Use xref-find-definitions in project B.
3. I can go back via xref-pop-marker-stack in B
4. but I cann't go back in project A since xref--marker-ring is shared between different projects.

Is there any possible to make xref--marker-ring works will with project.el?

Comment: `C-h v xref-history-storage` maybe? It is set to `xref-global-history` but `xref-window-history` is provided  and you may be able to write your own `xref-project-history` to do what you want.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I found this is added in 29.1. I will try after upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

In Emacs 29, we can fix this issue by

```
(setq xref-history-storage 'xref-window-local-history)
```

Emacs 29 is amazing!